# Creating List Classes in C#

Tags: c#

I have a question, not sure if it makes sense, but I couldn't find any answers related to it.
While creating an entity class I was thinking is it possible to create a class which in itself could be used as a list.
The way I do it currently is, I m not sure if its obsolete

```
MyEntityClass entityObj = new MyEntityClass();
List<MyEntityClass> entityList = new List<MyEntityClass>();
entityList.Add(entityObj);
```

is there an advanced to way to accomplish the same  in C#?

Comment: If you say why do you want to do this. It would be easier to answer.

Comment: You *could* make a collection container class. If you're not adding any further functionality, though, why would you? The generic collections in .NET are generally going to cover anything you need.

Comment: Occam's razor tells you not to needlessly multiply entities.

Comment: What you are doing is not obsolete in any way.

Comment: See [Why not inherit from List<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/719186)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement iEnumerable interface on your base class, this will force you to implement de definition for that interface, that will make the base clase behave as you wish.